# Calculate only distinct rows

Tags: mysql

So I have a database table:

```
projectNo| process | studio     | requiredNo |  
---------+---------+------------+------------+
16090001 | ANM     | APEX       | 10         |
16090001 | ANM     | BASECAMP   | 10         |
16090001 | BGD     | CANVAS     | 15         |
16090001 | BGD     | PALETTE    | 15         |
```

I want to calculate required number. But when I do

```
SELECT SUM(requiredNo) FROM process WHERE projectNo='$projectNo'
```

I get 50. But it should be 25 only, because process is the same but studio is defferent. However I need to calculate by process. So how can I calculate only distinct processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(mreq)
from
(
    select max(requiredNo) as mreq
    from process 
    where projectNo='$projectNo'
    group by process
) tmp
```

The inner select gets the highest `requiredNo` for each process. The outer select sums that up.